# Adding public attribute in Django model

Tags: python, django, models

giving users the option of making a topic public. This would
require an attribute called public as part of the Topic model (this should be set to False by default) and a form element on the new_topic page that allows the user to change a topic from private to public[enter link description here][1]

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic."""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text[:50] + "..."enter code here
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Adding an attribute called public in Topic model and it needs to be setup False by default !

Comment: Below is the E book Page number 382 exercise 20-5                                                                                        https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc/blob/master/chapter_20/learning_logs/models.py

Comment: public = models.BooleanField(default=False)

Comment: Hi Doner,  I think your method is right in public attribute change .                               Thanks  ,  but this problem is not totally solved .     The second part of this question is  form element on the new_topic page that allows the user to change a topic from private to public     ,  I am not sure how to make that change in the new_topic html file .

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add it as a field on your `Topic` model:

`public = models.BooleanField(default=False)`

Then add it to the list of fields of your `TopicForm` and it will be rendered on the form automatically:

`fields = ['text', 'public']`

Answer (score -1):

I am also stuck at this point. I have solution for the form element on the template. I have implemented it like checkbox:

new_topic.html

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="public"/> Public</label>
```

I have edited forms.py by adding meta attribute *public*:

forms.py

```
class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}
        public = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

and in views.py under new_topic function I have added check for checkbox:

```
@login_required
def new_topic(request):
    """Add a new topic."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TopicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_topic = form.save(commit=False)
            new_topic.owner = request.user
            if request.POST["public"]:
                new_topic.public = True
            new_topic.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', context)
```

When clicking on the checkbox, attribute public is properly changed to true, but I can not override @login_required for that topic. To be precise, newly created topic is not made public. So it would be great if somebody has solution on this point

Comment: This is really way more complicated than it needs to be. Please see my answer.